# is it better to code on R script instead of using its function?

Tags: r, data-science

I want to ask is it better to use loop functions in r scripts rather using its library cran? Like, I can code normalization function but should I use scale function for this?

I am new in data sciences.

Comment: This question will be closed because it's too broad and opinion based. What is better depends on a lot of things, but if there's no difference at all on the output using a package is just easier.

Comment: @Molx this normally would be a broad question, but because of how R is designed there absolutely is a better option than using loops. Most times even using `lapply` or a version of the `-apply` functions is way better than  loops when creating your own function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not an opinion based question. Answer (if I understand correctly the question) is only one: it is MUCH better to use package functions, because they are faster. MUCH, MUCH faster. Let me introduce a simple example:

```
library(microbenchmark)
x <- rnorm(10000)

mysum <- function(x)
{
   sumvar <- 0
   for(el in x)
   {
      sumvar <- sumvar + el  
   }
   sumvar
}

microbenchmark(sum(x), mysum(x))
```

And results:

```
Unit: microseconds
     expr      min       lq       mean    median        uq      max neval
   sum(x)    8.086    8.708   10.49947    9.6415   11.6625   24.258   100
 mysum(x) 3266.458 3377.486 3653.57448 3511.6825 3751.1545 5396.202   100
```

It is because package functions are usually implemented in C/C++ and they are fast. Loops in R are SLOW. Very slow. So if you don't want to implement your functions in C/C++ and make R interface for them, you better use package functions.

Of course, it is only one reason, which is R-dependent. Another, which do not depend on language, is e.g. that package functions are tested by many users, so they are more robust, and so on, which is actually too broad topic.

EDIT: yes, apply functions are generally better than simple `for` loops, but they are still not as fast as C/C++ implementations. I don't have fancy example, so here is a very simple one (comparison of the three approaches):

```
makeTwice <- function(x)
{
   ret <- numeric(length(x))
   for(i in 1:length(x))
   {
      ret[i] <- 2*x[i]  
   }
   ret
}
microbenchmark(2*x, unlist(lapply(x, function(el){2*el})), makeTwice(x))

Unit: microseconds
                                           expr       min         lq       mean    median        uq       max neval
                                          2 * x     7.464     8.8635    17.0367    16.794    18.349    69.664   100
 unlist(lapply(x, function(el) {     2 * el }))  6129.545  6818.4150  7786.6555  7265.792  8571.535 14864.356   100
                                   makeTwice(x) 11471.010 12193.3130 14381.6559 13334.380 14313.727 87065.413   100
```

Comment: This is a very good reason to learn to use the suite of apply functions in leu of for loops.

Comment: i got it now, thank you :)

Comment: I am actually writing a code that will first normalize data then after some functions it will de-normalize it. I know the command for normalization but don't know about de-normalization,I searched a lot and found **FLR** and **RecommenderLab** provide it but its not working.